# How can a program find out if it is running in Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2016

It seems both have a version string starting with 10.0 and the only difference is the build number.

Comment: So check the build number?

Comment: That's the only thing I can do now, but I wish there were another way to get the OS release name directly.